# OpenLayers.Layer.Text and bounding box

Tags: openlayers

I would like to display a lot of point (300/400) in IE with popup on them on a map. 
I tried to use OpenLayers.Layer.Vectors, it works but is far too slow.
So I tried OpenLayers.Layer.Text, but this one doesn't seem to send the BBOX parameter. So I presume I should send back the file containing all the points of the map but that's something like 35000 points ...

Have you ever done with that much point, is it still fast enough ?

Is there another way to be able to do this ? (I'm using my own server to respond to WMS and Vector layer and using an external server like mapguide or other is not an option).

Thanks a lot for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

35000 points is a lot of data for a Vector layer. From my experience displaying more than couple of hundreds of points almost always causes performance issues in Internet Explorer.

Typical solution in situation when you have a lot of data is to display it in a WMS layer and use WMSGetFeatureInfo or usual WFS search to fetch information about features.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, although I had some problem because instead of "layers" I used "layers_type" when creating the WMS layer (I should have read the spec more carefully). So now I have my hundred important point with feature, the others are WMS displayed and popup done with WMSGetFeatureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to edit those points, you can create a WMS layer.

We use some maps with 300 points rendered in a vector layer without performance issues.

Try to use firefox or chrome because with IE openlayers uses a slower renderer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, modifying the Browser is not an option either, the company only allows IE (yeah I know ...). Using WMS is ok to display my points, however I would like to have some popup info on them. And unless I'm completely wrong, you can't do that with WMS as it returns an image ?

Comment: Yes you can, using the GetFeatureInfo request.